# Plot a sample trajectory in StreamPlot

Tags: differential-equations

I am stuck in what it should be a very simple task, and I wonder if you could give me some light on this: I have the following two differential equations:

```
(*First Differential Equation*)
DE1 := x' = -3*y*((a + 1)*x + e*x^2); 

(*Second Differential Equation*)
DE2 := y' = -y^2 - (1/6)*((3*a + 1)*x + 3*e*x^2);
```

This DE, with `a = -1.35` and `e = +1`, produce the following StreamPlot:

```
  VF = StreamPlot[{DE2, DE1}, {y, -0.8, 0.8}, {x, 0, 1.5}, 
  PlotLabel -> "FIG. 1 - e = +1 and a < -1", 
  FrameLabel -> {"y", "x"}, LabelStyle -> {Bold}, StreamStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

What I simply want is to draw some sample trajectories as thin lines in this phase plot. Here I show my attempt

```
(*Trajectories*)

(*First Differential Equation*)
DE1T := x1'[t] == -3*y1[t]*((a + 1)*x1[t] + e*x1[t]^2);

(*Second Differential Equation*)
DE2T := y1'[t] == -y1[t]^2 - (1/6)*((3*a + 1)*x1[t] + 3*e*x1[t]^2);


Traj1 = NDSolve[{DE1T, DE2T, y1[0] == 0.2, x1[0] == 1.62}, {y1, 
    x1}, {t, 0, 5}]; 
Traj2 = NDSolve[{DE1T, DE2T, y1[0] == 0.5, x1[0] == 1.62}, {y1, 
    x1}, {t, 0, 5}]; 
Traj3 = NDSolve[{DE1T, DE2T, y1[0] == -0.34, x1[0] == 0.36}, {y1, 
   x1}, {t, 0, 10}]; 
TrajShow = 
 ParametricPlot[
  Evaluate[{y1[t], x1[t]} /. {Traj1, Traj2, Traj3}, {t, 0, 50}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Gray}]];
Show[VF, TrajShow]
```

Giving the following:

[image]

The curved trajectory at the top is all right, but the other two, which should sink in the point where the arrows meet (technically, it is an equilibrium point behaving as an attractor), then continue as straight lines after passing through the point.

What is happening? I do not see my mistake. Also, am I doing it too complicated using a numerical approximation? is there any other way of doing this?

Thank you very much for you help.

Comment: You are almost there. The error is that you solve in Traj1 and Traj2 from 0 to 5, while in Traj3 - from 0 to 10. However, when you make the ParametricPlot you run the time t from 0 to 50. If you fix the times in the ParametricPlot equal to those you specified in NDSolve everything will work correctly. For example, put in all cases time from 0 till 50.